# CSS Fixed background z-index issue

Tags: css, position, background-image, z-index

Got a site here: http://www.bigideaadv.com/big_idea_v2/#blog

The issue I'm having is the blog has a div with a height of 340px and a fixed background-attachment.

```
.full-fixed-background {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 340px;
    background: url("images/blog_slide.jpg") 0 0 repeat fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    z-index: 3000;
}
```

If I change the position from relative to static, the background displays but a logo overlay from the top of the page displays over it. The css from that top logo is as follows:

```
.floating-logo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2500;
    margin-top: -94px;
    margin-left: -356.5px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 715px;
}

.floating-logo img {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 715px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2500;
}
```

Can anyone provide assistance no fixing the z-index issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your issue is. Could you please elaborate the question?

Comment: I'm very confused mate. I don't think I'm understanding your question.

Comment: btw z-index doesn't work with static positioned elements. It works only on non-static elements, if you looking to z-index static elements  it's not possible.

Comment: I understand position:static won't work with z-index. I was only mentioning it because when it's static, the background displays fine but an image overlay from the top of the page sits on top.

Upon further investigation, this div ".full-fixed-background" displays the background when it's about to be scrolled into view and after you've scrolled past it.

I need it to display always, not the white background it shows when in view.

Comment: Then set your `z-index` of your `.full-fixed-background` to a lower number than the `.floating-logo img` `z-index`. In your example above `.full-fixed-background` will always be on top because 3000 > 2500

Comment: .floating-logo img is supposed to be a lower number than .full-fixed-background. That's the weird thing. @Kierchon His example seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take the z-index off of the big idea fixed text.

```
.floating-logo{
   //just leave z index out of here
}

.floating-logo img{
   //here as well
}
```

Playing around in chrome developer tools it looks like it makes the image you want to show up then and the big idea text stays visible at the top.

Comment: I've removed the z-index as you've suggested and it's better but it's still popping in and out as I scroll. Is this an issue with fixed background images?

Comment: @DaveRottino Its working for me on your site now. Im using latest version of chrome

Comment: @DaveRottino I do see it blinking very randomly but its hard to tell why with just the developer tools. It almost looks like the image is refreshing randomly.

Answer (score 0):

z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

z-index will be ignored on elements `position:static;`